# sed, delete a line which is before another

Tags: bash, shell, sed

So I'm having this code, it is about the squid proxy, which is look for lines which matches the `$DELETE` variable.
If the user is typing `deleteall` to confirm, then the sed removes all lines matching `"s_test"`
Now I want the sed to remove the line which matches the $aclonly variable AND the line above, which can be variable too, it always starts with `"#PR[0-9]*"`
Thanks for any advice

```
Example:
#PR0000
http_access allow s_test                 d_test                  http_port
```

---

```
  function remove(){
source_acl=$(grep $DELETE /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf)
echo $source_acl
acl_only=$(echo $source_acl | cut -f2 -d" ")
echo "#$DELETE = $acl_only"
echo "#FOLGENE ACL/RULES GEFUNDEN"
grep $acl_only /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf
return=$?
if [ "$return" = "0" ];then
        echo "WRITE DELETEALL TO REMOVE SHOWN ALCs/RULES"
        echo "WRITE DELETE TO REMOVE ONLY SOURCE ACL WHICH MATCHES IP"
        read delete
        if [ "$delete" = "deleteall" ];then
                sed -i -e /$acl_only/d /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf
                return=$?
                if [ "$return" = "0" ];then
                        echo DELETE SEQUEZ COMPLETET
                else
                        echo ERROR
                fi
        fi
        if [ "$delete" = "delete" ];then
                sed -i -e /$DELETE/d /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf
                return=$?
                if [ "$return" = "0" ];then
                        echo DELETE SEQUEZ COMPLETET
                else
                        echo ERROR
                fi

        fi
else
echo NO MATCHES

fi
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using awk

You can use sed for this (see below) but awk is probably easier.  Try:

```
awk -v a="$aclonly" '$0~a{getline; last=$0; next} NR>1{print last} {last=$0} END{if (!(last~a))print last}' file
```

**How it works**

Awk implicitly reads through a file line by line.  This script uses two variables.  `a` contains the regex that we want to match.  `last` contains the previous line.

- `-v a="$aclonly"`

  This defines an awk variable `a` with a value equal to the shell variable `aclonly`.
- `$0~a{getline; last=$0; next}`

  If the current line, `$0`, matches the regex `a` (`$aclonly`), then ignore the current, get the next line, set `last` to this new line, and then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `NR>1{print last}`

  If this is not the first line, then print the previous line, `last`.
- `last=$0`

  Update the variable `last` with the contents of the current line, `$0`.
- `END{if (!(last~a))print last}`

  After we have read the final line in the file, print `last` as long as it does not match regular expression `a`.

**Two examples**

As a first test file, consider:

```
$ cat file
Example:
#PR0000
http_access allow s_test                 d_test                  http_port
```

If we run our command, only the first line prints:

```
$ awk -v a="$aclonly" '$0~a{getline; last=$0; next} NR>1{print last} {last=$0} END{if (!(last~a))print last}' file
Example:
```

As a second example, consider this file:

```
$ cat file2
Example:
#PR0000
http_access allow s_test                 d_test                  http_port
#PR0000
http_access allow s_test                 d_test                  http_port
other
text
#PR0000
http_access allow s_test                 d_test                  http_port
#PR0000
http_access allow s_test                 d_test                  http_port
last
```

For this file, the following prints:

```
$ awk -v a="$aclonly" '$0~a{getline; last=$0; next} NR>1{print last} {last=$0} END{if (!(last~a))print last}' file2
Example:
other
text
last
```

## Using sed

Nearly the same logic can be used in sed:

```
sed -n '/s_test/{n; $p; x; d}; x; 1!p; ${x;p;}' file
```

Applying this to our two test files:

```
$ sed -n '/s_test/{n; $p; x; d}; x; 1!p; ${x;p;}' file
Example:
$ sed -n '/s_test/{n; $p; x; d}; x; 1!p; ${x;p;}' file2
Example:
other
text
last
```

Comment: as you know, it is better to explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider grep: -B option allows you to specify number of lines before pattern match. Combined with -n also gives line number

> grep -n -B 1 pattern file

combined with other commands will give you just the line number of the line above pattern

> grep -n -B 1 pattern file | head -n 1 | sed 's/-..*//g'

this can then be used to delete the line number using sed, where N is line number

> sed 'N d' file

Comment: i like this idea of using grep to get the line number(s) and passing that onto sed to delete the line(s)